# refetch data every time you enter the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo

I have a screen where I run a query and then on the basis of its results, I render some items via the `UserList` component. Using a button in the UserList component, I run a mutation (to delete an item). In this case, since the components are linked. I passed the `deleteContact`function and used `refetch()` within it. So when I delete a user, the ui is automatically updated and the deleted user is removed.

However, I have another component to `AddContact` which is not really linked to the `Whitelist`component (except the navigation). So when I add a user and come back to the `Whitelist`screen, the ui is not updated. The new user is not being rendered. Is there any way I can call refetch() every time the `Whitelist`screen is revisited?

```
export const Whitelist: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   refetch()
  // }, []);

  const [deleteUserRelationMutation] = useDeleteUserRelationMutation({
    onCompleted: (index: number) => {
      refetch();
      Alert.alert('Contact Deleted');
    },
    onError: _onDeleteUserRelationError
  });

  const onDeleteContact = (relationId: number) => {
    deleteUserRelationMutation({
      variables: { id: relationId}
  })
  };

  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useUsersQuery({
    variables: {
      where: { id: 1 },
    },
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Container style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
<Item style={styles.addToWhitelist}>
          <Icon name="add" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddContact')} />
          <Text >Add contact</Text>
        </Item>
        <ContactList data={data} onDeleteContact={onDeleteContact}></ContactList>
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

```
export const ContactList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({ data, onDeleteContact }) => {

  if (!data) return null;
  return (
    <View style={styles.users}>
    {data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
      (item: { relatedUser: RelatedUser, type: RelationType, id: number}) => {
        const userName = item.relatedUser.firstName.concat(' ').concat(item.relatedUser.lastName);
        return (
          <View style={styles.item} key={item.id}>
              <View style={styles.nameNumber}>
            <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.deleteButtonContainer}>
              <Button
                onPress={() => onDeleteContact(item.id)}
                >
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      },
    )}
  </View>
  );
};
```

I tried calling `refetch` in `useEffect`. It works when I come from the homepage to the `whitelist`screen. However, it doesn't work when I go to the `add contact`screen, add a contact and then navigate back to the `whitelist`.

Also tried using this in Whitelist:

```
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('refetching data');
    refetch();
  }, [])
);
```

It gives me the `console.log('refetching data');`every time I return to the screen, but the ui is not updated so I am guessing it's not actually refetched.

Comment: `console.log('component name')` before `return (` - check if components are rendered ... if yes, problem with updates/reconsilation

Comment: I added the log before the whitelist's return. If I navigate to another screen from here and then come back, I should see the log but I don't see it. Means data is not being rendered every time. @xadm

Comment: then it's higher level problem - managing views/screens - router used? redux?

Comment: @xadm Not using redux for now. Navigation is with useNavigation from ```@react-navigation/native';```. And somehow the log works now, so it's rendering but not refetching

Comment: Also tried using useFocusEffect but that didn't work either. @xadm

Comment: ... but you know your cache updating code is wrong?

Comment: I wasn't using that update cache thing. Was trying to refetch data simply. Anyhow, it works with useFocusEffect :D @xadm

Comment: it's a workaround .. implement right cache updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `fetchPolicy` in the hook `useUsersQuery` to either `cache-and-network` or `network-only` to update the users list page whenever that page is visited.

**`cache-and-network`**

If you set `fetchPolicy` to `cache-and-network`, apollo will display the cached data first and makes a network call in the background to update the cache. Once the response is received, it'll update the cache, which in turn will re-render the component that invoked the hook. When the component re-renders, the user list will be updated.

Pros: No loader shown. Gives a "fast site" impression.

Cons: Potentially stale data is shown until the cache is updated (duration depends on how fast the query resolves).

This is useful for the pages where you don't expect the data to change frequently. If adding/deleting users is not a frequent operation, you can use this option.

**`network-only`**

If you set `fetchPolicy` to `network-only`, apollo will always make a network call to fetch the data. It'll never store the data in its cache.

Pros: Guaranteed up-to-date data is shown.

Cons: Need to show a loader while the network call is in progress. Gives a "slow site" impression.

If adding/deleting users is a frequent operation in your app, this is a better option as it ensures that up-to-date data is shown always.

You can read more about fetch policies in the official docs
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy